# Spring Cloud Ribbon throws exception called No instances available for serverurl

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-ribbon

I am using spring boot with spring could ribbon. I did all configuration of ribbon. But when I send a request to rest controller, it throws an exception called **No instances available for serverurl**. How can I fix this?

These are my configurations

application.yml

```
port: 8888

serverurl:
  ribbon:
    eureka:
      enabled: false
    listOfServers: localhost:8081,localhost:8082,localhost:8083
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 15000
```

Spring Boot Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RibbonClient(name = "serverurl", configuration = RibbonCongisuration.class)
public class Server {

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Server.class,args);
    }
}
```

Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/v1/clients")
public class ClientController {



    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{ID}")
    public ClientDTO findByID(@PathVariable("ID") String clientID){
       return  restTemplate.getForEntity("http://serverurl/api/v1/clients/"+clientID,ClientDTO.class).getBody();

    }
}
```

URL

```
http://localhost:8888/api/v1/clients/1234
```

Comment: Please show your dependencies

Comment: `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: That's not enough of them. I need all spring boot and cloud ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make sure `http://localhost:8081/api/v1/clients/1234` (8081/8082/8083) response.

2) Add `RibbonConfiguration` file for example:

```
@Configuration
public class RibbonConfiguration{
@Bean
public IRule ribbonRule() {
    return new BestAvailableRule();
}

@Bean
public IPing ribbonPing() {
    return new PingUrl();
}
```

}

3) Make sure you have this kind of pom dependency (for example):

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And

```
<dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Finchley.SR2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```